# Open Multiple Windows at Same Time, popupWindow and New Tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've been working on the ability to open not only a popupWindow, but also a _blank URL at the same time using javascript. Here is what I have:

```
newPopup('http://www.someurl.com');
newTab('http://www.otherurl.com');

function newPopup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(url,'popUpWindow','formatting stuff here'); }

function newTab(url) {
    newLink = window.open(url,'_blank'); }
```

I've tried inversing them (new window first then popup).

I've also tried:

```
var = setTimeout(Popup('http ....'),3000);
```

I've tried:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url:"http://....."});
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on this? I have noticed that when the popupWindow appears, an inspect element shows up on the extensions page, but not for the _blank. I can get either or, but never both.

Thanks

Comment: Sure it's not a browser limitation? Since the popup fiasco a decade ago a lot of browsers implement security measures that prevent multiple popups (and some prevent repeated alerts).

Comment: *"Does anyone have any thoughts on this?"* How 'bout: *Please* don't do that? ;-)

Comment: "_I have noticed that when the popupWindow appears, an inspect element shows up on the extensions page, but not for the _blank._" `developer tools` can be invoked on any page using Ctrl+Shift+I

Comment: It may be a browser limitation.  What I'm doing is a desired response, but I see how it can be abused. The pages are related; where the popupWindow has information about the newWindow. Anyway. How about, if the popupWindow is refreshed into the popup.html, is there a way to keep the popup.html from closing as soon as the newWindow is created? Maybe a persistent window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many grueling hours of working this over, I've finally got it to work. I feel a little dumb about it, as my question had the answer in it.

```
newPopup('http://www.someurl.com');
newTab('http://www.otherurl.com');

function newPopup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(url,'popUpWindow','formatting stuff here'); }

function newTab(url) {
    newTab = chrome.tabs.create({url: url});}
```

Unfortunately, I didnt try one load with window.open and the other with chrome.tabs.create, and so that they are using different fundamental procedures, it works like bacon on anything. :)

Thanks